# How to access a member of an stdClass in PHP

Tags: php, json, stdclass

I have a JSON object that I decoded, and I can't access the element because it throws an error.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [error] => InvalidRegistration
)

echo $device_response->error; // gives an error
```

How would I go about accessing attributes?

Below is whole array of response:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [multicast_id] => 5.3301797222004E+18
    [success] => 1
    [failure] => 3
    [canonical_ids] => 0
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [message_id] => 0:1388910534147789%25796c83f9fd7ecd
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [error] => InvalidRegistration
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [error] => InvalidRegistration
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [error] => InvalidRegistration
                )

        )

)
```

Below is how I am accessing it:

```
foreach ($responseBody->results as $device_response) {

        echo $device_response->error;

    }
```

Comment: "gives an error" --- what error? PS: for debugging `var_dump()` is more handy than `print_r()`

Comment: It throws notice, I want to check whether there is an `error` in response or not

Comment: @AdityaBhatt, *what* notice?

Comment: @Aditya Bhatt: if you want to check if it exists, why not use `isset()`?

Comment: How can I get `InvalidRegistration` in response

Comment: @geedubb, "json" is not code.  "php" is not code.  A *lot* of your edits are amazingly trivial things that aren't actually improving the post.

Comment: @AdityaBhatt, the code as written *should* work, given that `results` is an array, and you're iterating over it looking for an `error` value.  Can you tell us *exactly* what is happening instead of producing the correct output?  Are you, perhaps, noticing a single warning from PHP?  If so, can you please provide the *full and exact* error message?

Comment: @Charles: Yes its working, just my understanding problem. Thank you all guys for your quick response though :)

Comment: use the json_decode($retrievedresult, true); this will give you the array instead of object and you can access easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->foo = "var";
echo $obj->foo;
```

Comment: How does this even remotely begin to answer the question?

Comment: Does this prints "var" .